# What is the meaning of the fan shaped area behind my current position in those gps applications

Tags: gps, google-maps-navigation, gps-tracking, navigation, osmand

In osmand and other gps navigation applications, my current position is shown as a spot with a certain radius, the radius shows the accuracy of my position, sometimes there is a fan shaped area in that spot, what does that mean?

Comment: Can you supply a screenshot? That might help us identify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the direction we are facing when holding the device in front.
https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/issues/1476